# Cookie not setting with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to set a cookie with Flask after login and redirect on the front end in Javascript.

```
@app.route("/login")
@auth.login_required
def get_auth_token():
    token = g.user.generate_auth_token()
    request = make_response()
    token = str(token.decode("ascii"))
    request.set_cookie("token", value = token)
    return request, 200
```

No matter if I have the redirect in or not, the cookie never sets. I've tried commenting out my redirect on the front end, I've tried setting my cookie with `secure = false` but none of that seems to work. What am I missing? If needed, I can provide the generate_suth_token function, but I know that is working properly. I am serving on `localhost:5000` and using Flask 0.12.2, and received no cookie warnings in the server log.

Comment: FYI: I had a similar, but not same, issue. I was trying to set a cookie on a route that was a callback so wasnt access in the browser so couldnt set a browser session cookie. I just set it on a JS enable route instead. Easy to forget these things if one doesnt do such all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `Flask` service and client service are being hosted on different domains (e. g `Flask` uses 127.0.0.1:8080  and a client uses 127.0.0.1:3000) in this case, cookies should be set with `domain` parameter otherwise they will not be available.

```
resp.set_cookie('cookie_key', value="cookie_value", domain='127.0.0.1')
```

Find more info about `domain` parameter [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#response-objects)

Comment: This works and I can now see the cookie in the response header, but not in Chrome under Security/Cookies, guess that is a separate issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This is strange. Chrome (v. 66.0.3359.139) works fine for me. What Chrome version do you use?

Comment: I figured it out, it was a CORS isssue with my Ajax call preventing the cookie from being set.